# LEFT OUTER JOIN in Access (JET Red) returns zero rows when right-most table is empty - why?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I wrote a query that returns single row data from multiple unrelated tables, so they're joined using a dummy value (`[Key] = 1`). This query has been running against hundreds of different database instances (sharing the same database design) without issues until today when I saw that when one database ran this query it returned zero rows - which shouldn't be possible with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` query where the left-most inner query always returns rows (because it's a `COUNT(*)` query), so I investigated.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    t1_foo.*,
    t2_bar.*,
    t3_baz.*,
    t4_qux.*
FROM
    (
        (
            (
                SELECT
                    1 AS [Key],
                    COUNT(*) AS FooCount
                FROM
                    Foo
            ) AS t1_foo

            LEFT OUTER JOIN
            (
                SELECT
                    1 AS [Key],
                    COUNT(*) AS BarCount
                FROM
                    Bar

            ) AS t2_bar ON t1_foo.[Key] = t2_bar.[Key]
        )

        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                1 AS [Key],
                COUNT(*) AS BazCount
            FROM
                Baz

        ) AS t3_baz ON t1_foo.[Key] = t3_baz.[Key]
    )

    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            TOP 1
            1 AS [Key],
            [Version],
            [Build],
            [CreateDateTime],
            [Comment]
        FROM
            Qux
        ORDER BY
            [CreateDateTime] DESC

    ) AS t4_qux ON t1_foo.[Key] = t4_qux.[Key]
```

The MDB database that was returning zero rows for this query had zero rows in the `Qux` table which meant that this inner-query was returning no rows:

```
SELECT
    TOP 1
    [Version],
    [Build],
    [CreateDateTime],
    [Comment]
FROM
    Qux
ORDER BY
    [CreateDateTime] DESC
```

I ran the same query against a SQL Server version of the same database (exact same table design) where the `Qux` table was also empty) and SQL Server returned 1 row, with valid values for `t1_foo`, `t2_bar` and `t3_baz` and with `NULL`s in the corresponding output `t4_qux` columns.

I changed the `t4_qux` inner-query to return a single dummy row (as below) and the query returned a single row again:

```
SELECT
    TOP 1,
    1 AS [Key]
FROM
    Foo
WHERE
    1 = 1
```

...then I changed `t4_qux` to another query that would return zero rows and the entire query returned zero rows:

```
SELECT
    TOP 1,
    1 AS [Key]
FROM
    Foo
WHERE
    1 = 0
```

Microsoft purports that Access generally conforms to [ANSI SQL-89 Level 1](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/comparison-of-microsoft-access-sql-and-ansi-sql-93edf744-9070-4af8-bcf9-1953a87bd6e5) - I can't find a copy of the SQL-89 spec, but I assume it states that a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` should still return rows from left-side inner-queries, even if a right-side query returned zero rows.

Why is Access returning zero rows in a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` query when the right-side inner-query returns zero rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I still don't know *why* Access isn't conforming to expectations, I was able to implement a workaround by adding dummy data to the rightmost inner-query such that it will returns rows which never satisfy the `JOIN` criteria so that Access now returns the left-side query result rows and `NULL` values for the rightmost query.

My query is now this:

```
SELECT
    t1_foo.*,
    t2_bar.*,
    t3_baz.*,
    t4_qux.*
FROM
    (
        (
            (
                SELECT
                    1 AS [Key],
                    COUNT(*) AS FooCount
                FROM
                    Foo
            ) AS t1_foo

            LEFT OUTER JOIN
            (
                SELECT
                    1 AS [Key],
                    COUNT(*) AS BarCount
                FROM
                    Bar

            ) AS t2_bar ON t1_foo.[Key] = t2_bar.[Key]
        )

        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                1 AS [Key],
                COUNT(*) AS BazCount
            FROM
                Baz

        ) AS t3_baz ON t1_foo.[Key] = t3_foo.[Key]
    )

    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            TOP 1
            [Key],
            [Version],
            [Build],
            [CreateDateTime],
            [Comment]
        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                TOP 1
                1 AS [Key],
                [Version],
                [Build],
                [CreateDateTime],
                [Comment]
            FROM
                Qux
            ORDER BY
                [CreateDateTime] DESC

            UNION ALL

            SELECT
                TOP 1
                0 AS [Key],
                0 AS [Version],
                0 AS [Build],
                #01/01/2000# AS [CreateDateTime],
                '' AS [Comment]
            FROM
                FOO
        )
        ORDER BY
            [Key] DESC

    ) AS t4_qux ON t1_foo.[Key] = t4_qux.[Key]
```

I'm using `Foo` as the source of the dummy row because it will always have rows in it. I can't use `MSysObjects` because the database denies `Read` permission to the `Admin` user for some reason.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this issue when using actual columns and not scalars for the join fields: `1 AS [Key]`. Can you confirm?

Comment: @Parfait I can reproduce in a blank Access database (Access 2000 file format, in Access 2019).

Comment: @Parfait I can't use an actual column because the data in the tables is unrelated. What alternatives are there to joining on a const scalar?

Comment: You might have simply hit an edge case and caught a bug! Your workaround may be the best solution. I tried with cross joins, saved queries, and others to no avail. With fuller context, there may be other solutions to joining non-grouped count aggregations to a potentially empty (temp?) table.